# MeteorJS : Find and display a value from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-helper

I am trying a select a value from the Mongo DB just like we do in SQL 
In SQL we query like :

```
SELECT column-name FROM table-name WHERE column-name = " something "
```

In the same way I am trying to do the following in Meteor to access the Mongo DB

```
collection.find({}, {Col-name1: {Col-name2 : 'xyz'}})
```

here I am trying to pull an integer value of `Col-name1` that corresponds to `Col-name2` : `xyz`

This leads to `[object Object]` that is a string in the html page. This should rather be a integer value. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: A simplified example document, along with examples for `Col-name1` and `Col-name2` would be an ideal addition to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You want,

```
collection.find({Col-name2 : 'xyz'}, {Col-name1: 1})
```

`{Col-name2 : 'xyz'}` is the criteria to match and `{Col-name1: 1}` is to return only `Col-name1` field in the document and the document by default will also have `_id`. If you dont want `_id`, you have to specify it like `{Col-name1: 1, _id: 0}`

Also mongodb, doesn't return the field value. It always return as document/s. So, you have to access the field yourself in your code. For example, to access `Col-name1` from a returned document, you have to use

```
document['Col-name1']
```

in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the issue starts here : Col-name1: Here 1 cannot be given as in my case Col-name1 has a dynamic value that changes every time on Page load

Comment: @Gemcode, You use bracket syntax to achieve that. For example, `var fieldName = 'Col-name1';` and use that variable to access the field like `var value = document[fieldName];`

Comment: : function starts    { var fieldName = 'Col-name1';
var value = document[fieldName]; return " the result is " collection.find({},{value: {Col-name2 : 'xxx'}})  I tried in this way but still it returns a object

Comment: I think you are dealing as an object when you actually have array at hand. Can you improve on that?